# Using Java's Scanner in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to use a Java Scanner to pick apart input from clojure's read-line. I think this is just a basic error that I can't find being very new to Clojure. The code is as follows:

```
(defn select-option
  []

(def option (read-line))
(println "test")
(def s (Scanner. option))
(println "test")
(def opt (.next s))
(println "test")

(case opt ("s"  (println "case test")
                (def lastn (.next s))
                (def firstn (.next s))
                (new-student lastn firstn))))
```

But I get the following output upon entering "s firstName lastName"

```
test
test
test
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  GradingSystem1.core/select-option (NO_SOURCE_FILE:12)
```

I would think its an error in my usage of java code, but any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra set of parens in `("s" ..)` which is being interpreted as a function call to the function "s". This crashes because "s" is not a function. It is also better to use `let` to define names inside a function, as using `def` here is not safe for concurrent operations.

One translation could look something like this:

```
(defn select-option []                       
  (let [option (read-line)                   
        _ (println "test")                   
        s (Scanner. option)                  
        _ (println "test")                   
        opt (.next s)                        
        _ (println "test")]                  
    (case opt                                
       "s"  (println "case test")             
      (let [lastn (.next s)                  
            firstn (.next s)]                
        (new-student lastn firstn)))))
```

Def always defines a top level var so if you use it in a function all instances of that function will share the *same* values and will interfere with each other. In Clojure the construct for defining lexical scope is the `let` expression. In the above example I use the name `_` for values that I'm not going to do anything with (the result of printing), this is just a convention though it demonstrates that it is ok to use the same name more than once in a let expression (later ones can use the previous values if they want).

Comment: I'm terrible at finding extra parenthesis, thanks! Its very un-clojurely as it stands, I had let originally but changed it in an attempt to fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: Paredit (for emacs and vim) is a pain in the ... to learn, though it is highly addictive and makes things like extra ()s (not quite) go away. I hardly thing about the ()s when using it.